kotlin drawing program drawings disappear
I am making a paint drawing application in Kotlin language. Drawing, coloring, undo, clear, save etc. everything works. But when I change the form while drawing, the drawings I make disappear. I want to draw a little, switch to another form and come back but my drawings should not be deleted.
package com.coding.curvedbottomnavigationapp

import android.content.Context
import android.graphics.*
import android.os.Environment
import android.util.AttributeSet
import android.view.MotionEvent
import android.view.View
import android.widget.Toast // Toast kütüphanesi eklendi
import java.io.File
import java.io.FileOutputStream
import java.io.IOException

class PaintView(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : View(context, attrs) {

    private var currentPaint = Paint().apply {
        isAntiAlias = true
        style = Paint.Style.STROKE
        strokeJoin = Paint.Join.ROUND
        strokeCap = Paint.Cap.ROUND
        strokeWidth = 10f
        color = Color.BLACK // Varsayılan renk siyah
    }

    private var strokeWidth = 10f
    private var paintColor = Color.BLACK

    // Her bir çizim yolunu ve ona karşılık gelen Paint nesnesini saklayacağımız yapı
    private val paths = mutableListOf<Pair<Path, Paint>>()
    private var currentPath: Path? = null

    override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas)

        // Tüm yolları ve onların kendi boyama stillerini çiz
        for ((path, paint) in paths) {
            canvas.drawPath(path, paint)
        }

        // Halen çizilmekte olan yolu çiz
        currentPath?.let { canvas.drawPath(it, currentPaint) }
    }

    override fun onTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
        val point = PointF(event.x, event.y)
        when (event.action) {
            MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {
                // Yeni bir yol oluştur ve onu mevcut boyama ayarlarıyla başlat
                currentPath = Path().apply {
                    moveTo(point.x, point.y)
                }
                return true
            }
            MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE -> {
                // Yolu güncelle
                currentPath?.lineTo(point.x, point.y)
            }
            MotionEvent.ACTION_UP -> {
                // Çizim bitince yolu ve boyama ayarlarını sakla
                currentPath?.let {
                    paths.add(Pair(it, Paint(currentPaint))) // Paint nesnesini kopyalayarak sakla
                    currentPath = null
                }
            }
        }
        invalidate() // Ekranı güncelle
        return true
    }

    // Renk değiştirme fonksiyonu
    fun setPaintColor(color: Int) {
        paintColor = color
        currentPaint.color = color // Mevcut boyama stiline yeni rengi uygula
        invalidate()
    }

    // Kalem genişliği değiştirme fonksiyonu
    fun setStrokeWidth(width: Float) {
        strokeWidth = width
        currentPaint.strokeWidth = width // Mevcut boyama stiline yeni kalem genişliğini uygula
        invalidate()
    }

    // Geri alma fonksiyonu
    fun undo() {
        if (paths.isNotEmpty()) {
            paths.removeAt(paths.size - 1)
            invalidate()
        }
    }

    // Tüm çizimleri temizleme fonksiyonu
    fun clear() {
        paths.clear()
        invalidate()
    }

    // Çizimi kaydetme fonksiyonu
    fun saveDrawing() {
        // Çizimi bitmap olarak oluştur
        val bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
        val canvas = Canvas(bitmap)
        draw(canvas) // Çizimi bitmape çiz

        // Kaydetme işlemi
        val file = File(context.getExternalFilesDir(null), "drawing_${System.currentTimeMillis()}.png")
        try {
            FileOutputStream(file).use { output ->
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, output)
                Toast.makeText(context, "Çizim kaydedildi: ${file.absolutePath}", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
            Toast.makeText(context, "Kaydetme işlemi başarısız.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }
}

package com.coding.curvedbottomnavigationapp.fragments

import android.Manifest
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import android.graphics.Color
import android.os.Bundle
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.SeekBar
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import com.coding.curvedbottomnavigationapp.MainActivity
import com.coding.curvedbottomnavigationapp.R
import com.coding.curvedbottomnavigationapp.PaintView
import java.util.*


class HomeFragment : Fragment(), TextToSpeech.OnInitListener {

    private lateinit var paintView: PaintView
    private lateinit var buttonUndo: Button
    private lateinit var buttonClear: Button
    private lateinit var buttonSave: Button
    private lateinit var seekBarStrokeWidth: SeekBar
    private lateinit var tts: TextToSpeech // TTS tanımlandı

    companion object {
        private const val STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE = 1001
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        paintView = view.findViewById(R.id.paintView)
        buttonUndo = view.findViewById(R.id.buttonUndo)
        buttonClear = view.findViewById(R.id.buttonClear)
        buttonSave = view.findViewById(R.id.buttonSave)
        seekBarStrokeWidth = view.findViewById(R.id.seekBarStrokeWidth)

        // Text-to-Speech başlatma
        tts = TextToSpeech(context, this)

        // İzinleri kontrol et
        requestStoragePermissions()

        // Geri alma işlemi
        buttonUndo.setOnClickListener {
            paintView.undo()
            playColorExplanation("Çizim geri alındı")
        }

        // Temizleme işlemi
        buttonClear.setOnClickListener {
            paintView.clear()
            playColorExplanation("Ekran temizlendi")
        }

        // Kalem kalınlığını ayarlama
        seekBarStrokeWidth.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(object : SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener {
            override fun onProgressChanged(seekBar: SeekBar?, progress: Int, fromUser: Boolean) {
                paintView.setStrokeWidth(progress.toFloat())
            }

            override fun onStartTrackingTouch(seekBar: SeekBar?) {}
            override fun onStopTrackingTouch(seekBar: SeekBar?) {}
        })

        // Kaydetme işlemi
        buttonSave.setOnClickListener {
            paintView.saveDrawing() // Çizimi kaydet
            playColorExplanation("Muhteşem bir resim kaydettin")
        }

        // Renk seçimi butonları için tıklama olaylarını ekleme
        view.findViewById<Button>(R.id.buttonRed).setOnClickListener {
            paintView.setPaintColor(Color.RED)
            playColorExplanation("Kırmızı renk seçildi") // Sesli uyarı
        }

        view.findViewById<Button>(R.id.buttonGreen).setOnClickListener {
            paintView.setPaintColor(Color.GREEN)
            playColorExplanation("Yeşil renk seçildi") // Sesli uyarı
        }

        view.findViewById<Button>(R.id.buttonBlue).setOnClickListener {
            paintView.setPaintColor(Color.BLUE)
            playColorExplanation("Mavi renk seçildi") // Sesli uyarı
        }

        view.findViewById<Button>(R.id.buttonYellow).setOnClickListener {
            paintView.setPaintColor(Color.YELLOW)
            playColorExplanation("Sarı renk seçildi") // Sesli uyarı
        }

        view.findViewById<Button>(R.id.buttonBlack).setOnClickListener {
            paintView.setPaintColor(Color.BLACK)
            playColorExplanation("Siyah renk seçildi") // Sesli uyarı
        }
    }

    // TTS başlatıldığında bu fonksiyon çalışır
    override fun onInit(status: Int) {
        if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
            // Dil olarak Türkçe seçiyoruz
            val result = tts.setLanguage(Locale("tr", "TR"))
            if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
                speakOut("Bu dil desteklenmiyor")
            }
        } else {
            speakOut("Text to Speech başlatılamadı")
        }
    }

    // Sesli mesaj oynatma fonksiyonu
    private fun speakOut(message: String) {
        tts.speak(message, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null, "")
    }

    // Text-to-Speech ile renk seçimi açıklaması yaparken müziği durdurma ve yeniden başlatma
    private fun playColorExplanation(message: String) {
        (activity as? MainActivity)?.let { mainActivity ->
            val wasPlaying = mainActivity.isMusicPlaying() // mediaPlayer yerine getter kullanılıyor
            mainActivity.pauseMusic()
            speakOut(message)

            tts.setOnUtteranceCompletedListener {
                // Eğer müzik başlangıçta çalıyorduysa tekrar başlat
                if (wasPlaying) {
                    mainActivity.playMusic()
                }
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        // TTS kaynağını serbest bırak
        if (tts != null) {
            tts.stop()
            tts.shutdown()
        }
        super.onDestroy()
    }

    private fun requestStoragePermissions() {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(requireContext(), Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(requireActivity(), arrayOf(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE), STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE)
        }
    }
}

Hello everyone, I am making a paint drawing application in Kotlin language. Drawing, coloring, undo, clear, save etc. everything works. But when I change the form while drawing, the drawings I make disappear. I want to draw a little, switch to another form and come back but my drawings should not be deleted.
package com.coding.curvedbottomnavigationapp

import android.content.Context
import android.graphics.*
import android.os.Environment
import android.util.AttributeSet
import android.view.MotionEvent
import android.view.View
import android.widget.Toast // Toast kütüphanesi eklendi
import java.io.File
import java.io.FileOutputStream
import java.io.IOException

class PaintView(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : View(context, attrs) {

    private var currentPaint = Paint().apply {
        isAntiAlias = true
        style = Paint.Style.STROKE
        strokeJoin = Paint.Join.ROUND
        strokeCap = Paint.Cap.ROUND
        strokeWidth = 10f
        color = Color.BLACK // Varsayılan renk siyah
    }

    private var strokeWidth = 10f
    private var paintColor = Color.BLACK

    // Her bir çizim yolunu ve ona karşılık gelen Paint nesnesini saklayacağımız yapı
    private val paths = mutableListOf<Pair<Path, Paint>>()
    private var currentPath: Path? = null

    override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas)

        // Tüm yolları ve onların kendi boyama stillerini çiz
        for ((path, paint) in paths) {
            canvas.drawPath(path, paint)
        }

        // Halen çizilmekte olan yolu çiz
        currentPath?.let { canvas.drawPath(it, currentPaint) }
    }

    override fun onTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
        val point = PointF(event.x, event.y)
        when (event.action) {
            MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {
                // Yeni bir yol oluştur ve onu mevcut boyama ayarlarıyla başlat
                currentPath = Path().apply {
                    moveTo(point.x, point.y)
                }
                return true
            }
            MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE -> {
                // Yolu güncelle
                currentPath?.lineTo(point.x, point.y)
            }
            MotionEvent.ACTION_UP -> {
                // Çizim bitince yolu ve boyama ayarlarını sakla
                currentPath?.let {
                    paths.add(Pair(it, Paint(currentPaint))) // Paint nesnesini kopyalayarak sakla
                    currentPath = null
                }
            }
        }
        invalidate() // Ekranı güncelle
        return true
    }

    // Renk değiştirme fonksiyonu
    fun setPaintColor(color: Int) {
        paintColor = color
        currentPaint.color = color // Mevcut boyama stiline yeni rengi uygula
        invalidate()
    }

    // Kalem genişliği değiştirme fonksiyonu
    fun setStrokeWidth(width: Float) {
        strokeWidth = width
        currentPaint.strokeWidth = width // Mevcut boyama stiline yeni kalem genişliğini uygula
        invalidate()
    }

    // Geri alma fonksiyonu
    fun undo() {
        if (paths.isNotEmpty()) {
            paths.removeAt(paths.size - 1)
            invalidate()
        }
    }

    // Tüm çizimleri temizleme fonksiyonu
    fun clear() {
        paths.clear()
        invalidate()
    }

    // Çizimi kaydetme fonksiyonu
    fun saveDrawing() {
        // Çizimi bitmap olarak oluştur
        val bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
        val canvas = Canvas(bitmap)
        draw(canvas) // Çizimi bitmape çiz

        // Kaydetme işlemi
        val file = File(context.getExternalFilesDir(null), "drawing_${System.currentTimeMillis()}.png")
        try {
            FileOutputStream(file).use { output ->
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, output)
                Toast.makeText(context, "Çizim kaydedildi: ${file.absolutePath}", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
            Toast.makeText(context, "Kaydetme işlemi başarısız.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }
}

package com.coding.curvedbottomnavigationapp.fragments

import android.Manifest
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import android.graphics.Color
import android.os.Bundle
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.SeekBar
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import com.coding.curvedbottomnavigationapp.MainActivity
import com.coding.curvedbottomnavigationapp.R
import com.coding.curvedbottomnavigationapp.PaintView
import java.util.*


class HomeFragment : Fragment(), TextToSpeech.OnInitListener {

    private lateinit var paintView: PaintView
    private lateinit var buttonUndo: Button
    private lateinit var buttonClear: Button
    private lateinit var buttonSave: Button
    private lateinit var seekBarStrokeWidth: SeekBar
    private lateinit var tts: TextToSpeech // TTS tanımlandı

    companion object {
        private const val STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE = 1001
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        paintView = view.findViewById(R.id.paintView)
        buttonUndo = view.findViewById(R.id.buttonUndo)
        buttonClear = view.findViewById(R.id.buttonClear)
        buttonSave = view.findViewById(R.id.buttonSave)
        seekBarStrokeWidth = view.findViewById(R.id.seekBarStrokeWidth)

        // Text-to-Speech başlatma
        tts = TextToSpeech(context, this)

        // İzinleri kontrol et
        requestStoragePermissions()

        // Geri alma işlemi
        buttonUndo.setOnClickListener {
            paintView.undo()
            playColorExplanation("Çizim geri alındı")
        }

        // Temizleme işlemi
        buttonClear.setOnClickListener {
            paintView.clear()
            playColorExplanation("Ekran temizlendi")
        }

        // Kalem kalınlığını ayarlama
        seekBarStrokeWidth.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(object : SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener {
            override fun onProgressChanged(seekBar: SeekBar?, progress: Int, fromUser: Boolean) {
                paintView.setStrokeWidth(progress.toFloat())
            }

            override fun onStartTrackingTouch(seekBar: SeekBar?) {}
            override fun onStopTrackingTouch(seekBar: SeekBar?) {}
        })

        // Kaydetme işlemi
        buttonSave.setOnClickListener {
            paintView.saveDrawing() // Çizimi kaydet
            playColorExplanation("Muhteşem bir resim kaydettin")
        }

        // Renk seçimi butonları için tıklama olaylarını ekleme
        view.findViewById<Button>(R.id.buttonRed).setOnClickListener {
            paintView.setPaintColor(Color.RED)
            playColorExplanation("Kırmızı renk seçildi") // Sesli uyarı
        }

        view.findViewById<Button>(R.id.buttonGreen).setOnClickListener {
            paintView.setPaintColor(Color.GREEN)
            playColorExplanation("Yeşil renk seçildi") // Sesli uyarı
        }

        view.findViewById<Button>(R.id.buttonBlue).setOnClickListener {
            paintView.setPaintColor(Color.BLUE)
            playColorExplanation("Mavi renk seçildi") // Sesli uyarı
        }

        view.findViewById<Button>(R.id.buttonYellow).setOnClickListener {
            paintView.setPaintColor(Color.YELLOW)
            playColorExplanation("Sarı renk seçildi") // Sesli uyarı
        }

        view.findViewById<Button>(R.id.buttonBlack).setOnClickListener {
            paintView.setPaintColor(Color.BLACK)
            playColorExplanation("Siyah renk seçildi") // Sesli uyarı
        }
    }

    // TTS başlatıldığında bu fonksiyon çalışır
    override fun onInit(status: Int) {
        if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
            // Dil olarak Türkçe seçiyoruz
            val result = tts.setLanguage(Locale("tr", "TR"))
            if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
                speakOut("Bu dil desteklenmiyor")
            }
        } else {
            speakOut("Text to Speech başlatılamadı")
        }
    }

    // Sesli mesaj oynatma fonksiyonu
    private fun speakOut(message: String) {
        tts.speak(message, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null, "")
    }

    // Text-to-Speech ile renk seçimi açıklaması yaparken müziği durdurma ve yeniden başlatma
    private fun playColorExplanation(message: String) {
        (activity as? MainActivity)?.let { mainActivity ->
            val wasPlaying = mainActivity.isMusicPlaying() // mediaPlayer yerine getter kullanılıyor
            mainActivity.pauseMusic()
            speakOut(message)

            tts.setOnUtteranceCompletedListener {
                // Eğer müzik başlangıçta çalıyorduysa tekrar başlat
                if (wasPlaying) {
                    mainActivity.playMusic()
                }
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        // TTS kaynağını serbest bırak
        if (tts != null) {
            tts.stop()
            tts.shutdown()
        }
        super.onDestroy()
    }

    private fun requestStoragePermissions() {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(requireContext(), Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(requireActivity(), arrayOf(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE), STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE)
        }
    }
}

Hello everyone, I am making a paint drawing application in Kotlin language. Drawing, coloring, undo, clear, save etc. everything works. But when I change the form while drawing, the drawings I make disappear. I want to draw a little, switch to another form and come back but my drawings should not be deleted.
Thanks in advance for your answers.

Here is a place to start:
https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/saving-state
I'll suggest one approach here.
The Fragment class has a method called onSaveInstanceState which you can override to keep track of UI state.  Classes which implement Parcelable (the Serializable of the Android world) can be saved in a manner that they can be recovered on reconstruction.
When you implement an onSaveInstanceState override that puts your Parcelable state in a Bundle, that data becomes available to you again in methods such as onCreateView and onViewCreated as the savedInstanceState parameter.  In one of these methods you check if savedInstanceState has data present, and if it does you can use that data to recreate the state of your views.
The difficult part of your coding is going to be taking the important values of your drawing data -- your List<Pair<Path, Paint>> property -- and creating Parcelable implementations to hold those values, for example the path shape, the path coordinates, the paint color, stroke, etc.
But once you have those classes, your implementation could be something like this:

Give your PaintView a method to access the current path-paint pair list (getter)
Also code a method on PaintView to take a list of path-paint pair data, set your current list and render all those paths (setter)
Override your fragment's onSaveInstanceState to call the view's getter and create a Parcelable representation of your list and save it in the bundle
Check savedInstanceState on fragment creation.  If there is data that was saved, reverse the operation and create the paint-path pair list from the Parcelable data and call the setter on PaintView to re-render your drawing.

This savedInstanceState approach will only work for simple drawings; for complex drawings the persistent data may be too large for the state bundle.
The Saving State with Fragments page also discusses using a ViewModel,  which could persist state for larger drawings.
